# Sql query getting name column null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25d42/6)

```
CREATE TABLE [Users_Reg]
(
   [User_ID]        [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT User_Reg_P_KEY PRIMARY KEY,
   [Name]           [varchar] (50) NOT NULL, 
   [Type]           [varchar] (50) NOT NULL /*Technician/Radiologist*/
)

CREATE Table [Study]
(
  [UID]             [INT] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Patient_Study_P_KEY PRIMARY KEY,
  [Radiologist]     [int], /*user id of Radiologist type*/
  [Technician]      [int], /*user id of Technician type*/

)


select * from Study
inner join Users_Reg
on Users_Reg.User_ID=Study.Radiologist
```

In patient_study table may be Radiologist or Technician have 0 value.
how i get technician name and radiologist name from query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to JOIN on the `users_reg` table twice to get the result. Once for the radiologist and the another for the technician:

```
select ps.uid,
  ur1.name rad_name,
  ur1.type rad_type,
  ur2.name tech_name,
  ur2.type tech_type
from Patient_Study ps
left join Users_Reg ur1
  on ur1.User_ID=ps.Radiologist
left join Users_Reg ur2
  on ur2.User_ID=ps.Technician;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25d42/21).  This will return both the radiologist and technician name/type for all patient studies.  If you want to replace the null in any of the columns, then you could use `COALESCE` similar to the following:

```
select ps.uid,
  coalesce(ur1.name, '') rad_name,
  coalesce(ur1.type, '') rad_type,
  coalesce(ur2.name, '') tech_name,
  coalesce(ur2.type, '') tech_type
from Patient_Study ps
left join Users_Reg ur1
  on ur1.User_ID=ps.Radiologist
left join Users_Reg ur2
  on ur2.User_ID=ps.Technician;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25d42/46)

Answer (score 3):

in your case you could use `isnull`:

```
select * 
from Patient_Study as PS
    inner join Users_Reg as U on U.User_ID = isnull(nullif(PS.Radiologist, ''), PS.Technician)
```

or two `left outer joins`:

```
select PS.*, isnull(UP.Type, UT.Type) as Type
from Patient_Study as PS
  left outer join Users_Reg as UP on UP.User_ID = PS.Radiologist
  left outer join Users_Reg as UT on UT.User_ID = PS.Technician;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25d42/20) with example.

As advice I might say - store `null` values in your table if you have no proper value

```
INSERT INTO Patient_Study(Radiologist,Technician)VALUES('1','2')
INSERT INTO Patient_Study(Radiologist,Technician)VALUES('1','')
INSERT INTO Patient_Study(Radiologist,Technician)VALUES(null,'2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25d42/12)

The code:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     Patient_Study
INNER JOIN Users_Reg
         ON CASE 
                WHEN Patient_Study.Radiologist = '' 
                THEN Patient_Study.Technician 
                ELSE Patient_Study.Radiologist 
            END = Users_Reg.User_ID;
```

If you ever make it NULL instead of "" (which i would prefer)

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     Patient_Study
INNER JOIN Users_Reg
         ON COALESCE(Patient_Study.Radiologist,Patient_Study.Technician) = Users_Reg.User_ID
```

I choose COALESCE instead of ISNULL, as you may add other technicians in there.

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

```
select *,'Radiologist' as StudiedBy from Patient_Study
inner join Users_Reg
on Users_Reg.User_ID=Patient_Study.Radiologist
and Patient_Study.Radiologist>0
Union
select *,'Technician' from Patient_Study
inner join Users_Reg
on Users_Reg.User_ID=Patient_Study.Technician 
and Patient_Study.Technician >0
```

I have added a flag StudiedBy to differentiate the Radiologist from Techinician.
You can add where condition to check for specific User_Reg

Answer (score 1):

```
select R.Name as TechnicianName,T.Name as RadiologistName 
from Patient_Study
inner join Users_Reg R
on Patient_Study.UID=R.User_ID

inner join Users_Reg T
on Patient_Study.UID=T.User_ID.
```

see

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25d42/41